# Why is this file not reading into my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, io

Can anyone tell me why my array is not filling up with the info I am trying to get from my data file? When I output the array it just gives me garbage. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// function main begins program execution
int main()
{
    /* input correct answers file */    
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;      // Array size
    int correctAnswers[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Array to hold correct answers
    int count = 0;                  // Loop counter variable
    ifstream inputFile;             // Input file stream object

    // open the file
    inputFile.open("c:\\correctanswers.txt");

    // read the numbers from the file into the array
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        inputFile >> correctAnswers[count];
        count++;
    }

    // close the file
    inputFile.close();

    // display the correct answers
    cout << "The correct answers are: ";
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        cout << correctAnswers[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying in Windows/Linux? What is the error message?

Comment: What is the contents of the file? Does file correctanswers.txt exists?

Comment: You do no error checking on the input stream.  My guess is that the file could not be opened, or that it does not contain integers.

Comment: Trying in windows. It is not giving me an error message; it compiles and runs, but when executing the cout command it displays the numbers in the array as a bunch of random numbers.

Comment: Oh gosh! Duh! The file does NOT contain integers. Thank you. ::embarassed::

Comment: You won't get error *messages*.  You need to catch errors yourself by checking the status of the stream after opening or reading.

Answer (score 0):

You never check to see if the stream is ever initialized to the desired state. I would begin by checking whether the stream is able open the given argument: if(inputFile.is_open)

Answer (score -1):

correctAnswers is an array of int, you are trying to copy onto it strings coming from the file. I suggest you to use an auxiliary variable to store the line grabbed from the file, then manipulate it as you want. Also, you probably want to make sure not to exceed the end of file limits...